# How can I install Windows 10 64-bit in El Capitan Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macos

I'm running OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 on an [early 2015 13-inch Retina MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp715?locale=en_US) (MacBookPro12,1) with Boot Camp Assistant 6.0.0 (519).

I have downloaded *Win10_EnglishInternational_x64.iso* from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

When I select this ISO and click Install in Boot Camp Assistent I am presented with the message below and I'm not able to continue.

> **Need 64-bit Windows 8 or later ISO file.**
>
> Boot Camp only supports 64-bit Windows 8 or later installation on this platform. Please use an ISO file for 64-bit Windows 8 or later installation.

What do I need to do/change/download for Boot Camp Assistant to accept Microsoft's official Windows 10 ISO as a valid "64-bit Windows 8 or later ISO file"

I also tried *en_windows_10_multiple_editions_x64_dvd_6846432.iso* that I can download from MSDN as a subscriber. This ISO file is also not accepted by Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: I don't have the cred to be able to answer on here, but you're likely using Chrome to download the ISO.  It has issues.  Download the iso with Safari and it will work.

Answer (score 6):

I think because you download an iso and mounted it (open it) and that silly error pop out. I just unmount and it's work

Comment: This is the right answer in my case

Comment: you rock man!!!

Answer (score 4):

Boot Camp Assistant accepts *Win10_SingleLang_EnglishInternational_x64.iso*

Comment: To clarify: from the [windows download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) under `Select Edition` you have to select the single language version. It will give you this message if you download the generic `Windows 10` edition, instead of the `Windows 10 Single Language` edition.

Comment: unmounting the disk worked :)