# Boot Camp not recognizing Windows 10 ISO

Tags: bootcamp, windows, dual-boot

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 10 on MacBook Pro, and Boot Camp Assistant is failing to recognize the ISO I've downloaded (from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).

I'm using an Early 2015 13" Macbook Pro, running El Capitan 10.11.4

On the first step in Boot Camp Assistant, I select the ISO and choose a partition size. When I click "Install", I get this error :

> **Need 64-bit Windows 8 or later ISO file.**
>
> Boot Camp only supports 64-but Windows 8 or later installation on this platform.

I have certainly downloaded the 64-bit version, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I tried the solutions in [How can I install Windows 10 64-bit in El Capitan Boot Camp?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214209/how-can-i-install-windows-10-64-bit-in-el-capitan-boot-camp), but none worked for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try re-downloading because the Microsoft website has a bug where it will sometimes terminate the iso download half way through, leaving you with an unfinished iso file. If the size of the iso you downloaded is less than 3.7 gigabytes, then it means its incomplete. You have to head to https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10ISO to download a new one.